# ScardTransmit always returning error 16

Tags: apdu, smartcard-reader, winscard

I am trying to build application in windows using the Winscard library to communicate with contactless  smartcard reader.
I am able to connect to the device but when I try so send some data using scardtransmit I get a error 16. I have attached the piece of code that I am using below

```
SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendPci = *SCARD_PCI_T1;
//SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendPci = *SCARD_PCI_RAW;
DWORD dwRecvLength;
BYTE pbRecvBuffer[258];
BYTE cmd1[260];
cmd1[0]= 0xA0;
cmd1[1]= 0x0D;
cmd1[2]= 0x01;
cmd1[3]= 0x00;
cmd1[4]= 0x01;
ULONG sendbuflen= 0x05;
dwRecvLength = sizeof(pbRecvBuffer);

rv2 = SCardTransmit(hCard, &pioSendPci , cmd1,sendbuflen ,NULL, pbRecvBuffer, &dwRecvLength);
```

Comment: How do you connect to the card reader (i.e. what parameters do you use)?

Answer (score 1):

The command you are trying to send does not look like a valid APDU.

A valid APDU (see ISO/IEC 7816-4) has this form (except for extended length APDUs):

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+
| CLA    | INS    | P1     | P2     | [Lc]   | [DATA]   | [Le]   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+
| 1 Byte | 1 Byte | 1 Byte | 1 Byte | 1 Byte | Lc Bytes | 1 Byte |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Where `Lc` contains the number of transmitted command `DATA` bytes or is empty (i.e. no `Le`) if there is no `DATA` bytes. `Le` encodes the number of expected response data bytes, with the special case `Le` empty indicating no expected response data bytes and `Le` = `0x00` indicating 256 (or maximum) expected reponse data  bytes.